# Manual traffic light conversion into automatic via Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to do a traffic light sequence which runs on a timed basis automatically without user input . I have now got the code working but it only runs through once and then stops so how can I change this so it keeps going? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var images = new Array()
images[0] = "image2.jpg";
images[1] = "image3.jpg";
images[2] = "image4.jpg";
setInterval("changeImage()", 3000);
var x=0;

function changeImage()
{
document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
x++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img" src="image1.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this automatic, you can either put it in a loop, or you can use the [`setInterval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

`var interval = setInterval(nextLightClick, 1500);`

This will loop indefinitely, running the function every 1500 milliseconds (1.5 seconds). If you want to stop it, you can simply say:

`clearInterval(interval);`

Here's an example -- note that I am changing the innerHTML, rather than the src, and I am using a div instead of image, but the logic will be exactly the same.

```js
var tlight = new Array("1green.jpg","2yellow.jpg","3red.jpg");
var index = 0;
var tlightLen = tlight.length;
var image = document.getElementById('firstlight');
image.innerHTML = tlight[index];
var interval;
function startInterval() {
  interval = setInterval(nextLightClick, 1500);
}
function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
function nextLightClick() {
    index++;
    if (index == tlightLen) 
        index = 0;
    image.innerHTML = tlight[index];
}
```

```html
  <span id="firstlight"></span></br>
  <button onclick="startInterval()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="stopInterval()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: @tomkenny Check the demo in my edited answer to see it in action